# nconf cannot generate nagios configure files

Tags: nagios

I installed a brand new nagios server and installed a fresh nconf. I just need to see how nconf can generate the configure files for ngaios.

But after I click **Generate Nagios config**, I got:

```
Nagios Core 4.0.5
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 04-11-2014
License: GPL

Website: http://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
Error: Cannot open main configuration file '/opt/htdocs/nconf/temp/test/Default_Collector.cfg' for reading!
Error processing main config file!
```

I thought nconf is to generate files, but it want to read a file. And I don't know what file I should provide to nconf. So confused, need help.

**BUT Default_Collector.cfg file doesn't exist**. There is no such directory /opt/htdocs/nconf/temp/test/. Empty in /opt/htdocs/nconf/temp/

**EDIT: permission setting**

```
[root@localhost nconf]# ll |grep ^d
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache root    4096 Dec 11  2011 ADD-ONS
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache root    4096 Dec 11  2011 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache  4096 Apr 30 11:14 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache root    4096 Dec 11  2011 config.orig
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache root    4096 Dec 11  2011 design_templates
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache root    4096 Dec 11  2011 img
drwxr-xr-x 9 apache root    4096 Dec 11  2011 include
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache  4096 Apr 30 11:28 output
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache  4096 Dec 11  2011 static_cfg
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache  4096 Apr 30 11:29 temp
[root@localhost nconf]# ps -ef|grep apache
root     15568 15528  0 10:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep apache
apache   26125     1  0 Apr29 ?        00:00:01 /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
apache   26126 26125  0 Apr29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi
apache   26127 26126  0 Apr29 ?        00:00:15 /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Comment: Just curious, why the down vote? Your answer was already found in google before I ask the question. No help at all.

Comment: just to confirm, this is a thing and filesystem perms do not seem to be the issue.  I have virtually cloned server environments and am trying to relocate nconf to a new server via rsync and get this error on the new server but not the old.  I know I've run into this once before and fixed it somehow, but can't remember.  It wasn't filesystem permissions, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, figured it out for me. In my case this was a fresh CentOS 6.8 installation with all default or epel packages installed via yum (nothing hand rolled for the system.)

At any rate, the support perl script nconf/bin/generate_config.pl has at least two perl package dependencies I was missing and was failing.  Although the wrapper script that runs generate_config.pl attempts to detect failures, it's not seeing the error from the perl script, so the wrapper script continues and essentially tries to create a new nagios configuration from nothing (because nothing was generated by generate_config.pl) thus this error.

running `yum install perl-DBI perl-DBD-MySQL` fixed the problem for me, but it could also be other missing perl packages or a different errors from generate_config.pl that is not getting recognized by the wrapper script.  My recommendation is try to run the perl script manually like `sudo -u apache /opt/nconf/bin/generate_config.pl`.  once you do get that portion working, you will need to clean out your /opt/nconf/temp folder before the web nconf app will let you generate another config set.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following directories are writable by the user nconf is running as.

```
/opt/htdocs/nconf/config 
/opt/htdocs/nconf/output 
/opt/htdocs/nconf/static_cfg 
/opt/htdocs/nconf/temp
```

Comment: there is no Default_Collector.cfg file, there is no such directory /opt/htdocs/nconf/temp/test/. Empty in /opt/htdocs/nconf/temp/

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: these directories are write-able to 'apache' user

Answer (score 0):

With current Ubuntu 18.04, this seems to be caused by current perl (5.26.1) not allowing a hash to be used as a reference, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044211/using-hash-as-a-reference-is-deprecated :

`Can't use a hash as a reference at /var/www/nconf/bin/lib/NConf/ExportNagios.pm line 1274.`

You can see more of the error (the web generator doesn't really say what's going on) by running generate_config.pl manually, something like this: `sudo -u www-data bin/generate_config.pl`

Hints about possible fixes are in https://github.com/nconf/nconf/issues/37